# How to translate Javascript require to Typescript import with const

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to import faktory (github.com/jbielick/faktory_worker_node).
The README suggests:

```
const faktory = require('faktory-worker');

faktory.register('ResizeImage', async ({ id, size }) => {
  const image = await Image.find(id);
  await image.resize(size);
});

faktory.work();
```

And I tried to translate it to Typescript:

```js
import faktory from 'faktory-worker';

faktory.register('ResizeImage', async ({ id, size }) => {
  const image = await Image.find(id);
  await image.resize(size);
});

faktory.work();
```

I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined` no matter what I do.
I thought I have to use `const` to somehow create an object but I just cannot figure out how.

I can keep the syntax but Typescript suggest best practice of import by the rule `no-var-requires: require statement not part of an import statement`

Comment: This module has TypeScript definitions, so it should work like this. Do you have the latest version? Typings have been added in 3.0.4 apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement typescript definitions of that module too: [index.d.ts](https://github.com/jbielick/faktory_worker_node/blob/master/index.d.ts)

E.G. save that file to folder `typings` in root and add the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

This will include the interfaces and register the methods.

There are other possibilities to achieve that [@types, typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: i mean without make my custom types for this module

Comment: @JurajKocan How is it working? The way I described above? 
You can `import faktory from 'faktory-worker'` ?

Comment: yes, in index.d.ts of this module is "export default faktory" no ts problem nor compile javascript

Comment: @JurajKocan Any chance you share this chunk of code?
Like I mentioned I can also import but then when I try to `faktory.register` it throws the mentioned exception `TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined`

Comment: Did you try it with my answer?

Comment: @OmerH i tried exactly your code exept the body of callback with module version 3.1.0... i suggest you to install this version. you should share your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `"esModuleInterop": true` to tsconfig.json resolved this issue for me, e.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
    // ...
  }
}
```